# ORA-04068 with Only Constant in Spec (DB 11.2.0.4)

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, constants

I have a package like this:

```
create or replace PACKAGE pkg_state
AS
   gv_test constant varchar(50) := 'Test!';

   FUNCTION get_variable
   RETURN VARCHAR2;
END pkg_state;
/

create or replace PACKAGE BODY pkg_state
AS

   FUNCTION get_variable
   RETURN VARCHAR2
   AS
   BEGIN
      RETURN 'TRUE';
   END get_variable;

END pkg_state;
/
```

My understanding was, that with [11.2.0.2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/whatsnew.htm#LNPLS110) constants wont change the package state.
But when Im changing the package body in another session I will get the 04068 Error. If the constant is in the Package Body everything works as expected but not with the constant in the Specification.

(Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production)

Any ideas? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking in the Oracle Forums (https://community.oracle.com/message/14756602#14756602) the following is the case:

The package has only a state with VARCHAR constants - not with number or bool.
(Exception: When the initialization is a computation, then it's still statefull:
 v_var constant number := 1+1; -- statefull).

This seems so be fixed with 12c (but calculations still result in statefulness).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if they fixed this issue in 11g database.
To avoid this use (I know it misses the point):

```
create or replace PACKAGE pkg_state
AS
   FUNCTION gv_test RETURN VARCHAR2;

   FUNCTION get_variable
   RETURN VARCHAR2;
END pkg_state;
/

create or replace PACKAGE BODY pkg_state
AS
   FUNCTION gv_test 
   RETURN VARCHAR2
   AS
   BEGIN
      RETURN 'Test!';
   END;

   FUNCTION get_variable
   RETURN VARCHAR2
   AS
   BEGIN
      RETURN 'TRUE';
   END get_variable;

END pkg_state;
/
```

Comment: That's why I added the link (here it states that it is fixed): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/whatsnew.htm#LNPLS110